# Traffic light implementation

Tags: vb.net

Can someone review this code for me?  I'm not completely sure I did this correctly. I also would like help creating the code for the "walk" "don't walk" lights.

I needed to create a traffic intersection. Each traffic light has a cycle of 31 seconds red, followed by 26 seconds green, followed by 3 seconds yellow. The red in the north-south direction starts at the same time as the green in the east-west direction. There will be a 60 second light cycle, and a 2 second overlap where the lights are red in all directions. The walk-don't walk signal reads walk for the 26 second green light, and don't walk for all other times.

```
Public Class _12
Private Sub N_S_G_Lights()
    pb_N.BackColor = Color.Green
    lbl_N.BackColor = Color.Green
    pb_S.BackColor = Color.Green
    lbl_S.BackColor = Color.Green
End Sub
Private Sub N_S_Y_Lights()
    pb_N.BackColor = Color.Yellow
    lbl_N.BackColor = Color.Yellow
    pb_S.BackColor = Color.Yellow
    lbl_S.BackColor = Color.Yellow
End Sub
Private Sub N_S_R_Lights()
    pb_N.BackColor = Color.Red
    lbl_N.BackColor = Color.Red
    pb_S.BackColor = Color.Red
    lbl_S.BackColor = Color.Red
End Sub
Private Sub W_E_G_Lights()
    pb_W.BackColor = Color.Green
    lbl_W.BackColor = Color.Green
    pb_E.BackColor = Color.Green
    lbl_E.BackColor = Color.Green
End Sub
Private Sub W_E_Y_Lights()
    pb_W.BackColor = Color.Yellow
    lbl_W.BackColor = Color.Yellow
    pb_E.BackColor = Color.Yellow
    lbl_E.BackColor = Color.Yellow
End Sub
Private Sub W_E_R_Lights()
    pb_W.BackColor = Color.Red
    lbl_W.BackColor = Color.Red
    pb_E.BackColor = Color.Red
    lbl_E.BackColor = Color.Red
End Sub
Private Sub _12_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    pb_N.BackColor = Color.Red
    pb_E.BackColor = Color.Red
    pb_S.BackColor = Color.Red
    pb_W.BackColor = Color.Red
    lbl_N.BackColor = Color.Red
    lbl_E.BackColor = Color.Red
    lbl_S.BackColor = Color.Red
    lbl_W.BackColor = Color.Red

End Sub

Private Sub Lights()
    If lbl_time.Text <= 33 Then
        W_E_R_Lights()
    ElseIf lbl_time.Text >= 34 And lbl_time.Text <= 58 Then
        W_E_G_Lights()
    ElseIf lbl_time.Text >= 59 Then
        W_E_Y_Lights()
    ElseIf lbl_time.Text >= 60 Then
        W_E_R_Lights()
    End If
    If lbl_time.Text <= 26 Then
        N_S_G_Lights()
    ElseIf lbl_time.Text >= 27 And lbl_time.Text <= 29 Then
        N_S_Y_Lights()
    ElseIf lbl_time.Text >= 30 Then
        N_S_R_Lights()
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub Timer_N_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer_N.Tick
    lbl_time.Text = Val(lbl_time.Text) + 1

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    lbl_time.Text = "55"
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    lbl_time.Text = "25"
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If lbl_time.Text <= 60 Then
        Lights()
    Else
        lbl_time.Text = "0"
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 5):

#### Naming.

`N_S_G_Lights` could be called `NorthSouthGreenLights`, but that wouldn't make it a much better name. Method names should start with a verb, they *do something*.

However, the pattern is consistent, which is a good thing. It's *redundant* though.

#### Structure.

The things you need to *do* depend on the *vocabulary* you're writing your code with - *methods* are *verbs*, *classes* are *subjects*. Classes are definitions for *objects*, which *encapsulate* a piece of functionality and *abstract* away the implementation details.

The first *object* I'd think of a design for, would be some `TrafficLight` class. I'd want the UI code to only have to be told *what color that traffic light is*, and draw the appropriate background color in that `PictureBox`.

The form code doesn't need to know about a `Timer` - it needs to know about a `TrafficLight`, and from that object it needs to know the `LightColor`, and it needs *to be notified* whenever the color changes.

I'd be expecting something like this in a class called `TrafficLight`:

```
Private Const RedSeconds As Integer = 31
Private Const GreenSeconds As Integer = 26
Private Const YellowSeconds As Integer = 3

Private LightTimer As Timer 'ticks every second

Private CurrentColor As Color

Public Event Changed(ByVal NewColor As Color)
```

I like that you have a single timer for the whole 60-second cycle, but the magic numbers  in `Lights()` make it hard to correlate what you've done with what the requirements are. Using constants as above, helps making the code more readable. The fact that your logic relies on UI values isn't very nice, too.

When you have a `TrafficLight` that raises an event that says *"Hey there, if it's of any interest to you, I'm changing my current color right now"* to your form, the form itself doesn't know how the `TrafficLight` operates, but it knows that when color changes, it needs to change the background color of some `PictureBox`:

```
Private Sub NorthSouthLight_Changed(ByVal NewColor As Color)

    NorthTrafficLightPicture.BackColor = NewColor
    NorthLabel.BackColor = NewColor

    SouthTrafficLightPicture.BackColor = NewColor
    SouthLabel.BackColor = NewColor

End Sub

Private Sub EastWestLight_Changed(ByVal NewColor As Color)

    EastTrafficLightPicture.BackColor = NewColor
    EastLabel.BackColor = NewColor

    WestTrafficLightPicture.BackColor = NewColor
    WestLabel.BackColor = NewColor

End Sub
```

What color that is, isn't important - it's conveyed by the `Changed` event, if a `TrafficLigth` wanted to be `Blue`, the form would happily comply.

---

**TL;DR**: In other words, I think your code could greatly benefit from a little bit more of an *Object-Oriented* approach, especially if this code is [vb.net](/questions/tagged/vb.net) (I was assuming [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) all along, when I came across a `Handles` keyword, which I haven't seen used in VBA).